# Averaging every n elements of a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, average

I would like to average every 3 values of an vector in Matlab, and then assign the average to the elements that produced it.

Examples:

```
x=[1:12];
y=%The averaging operation;
```

After the operation,

```
y=
[2 2 2 5 5 5 8 8 8 11 11 11]
```

Therefore the produced vector is the same size, and the jumping average every 3 values replaces the values that were used to produce the average (i.e. `1 2 3` are replaced by the average of the three values, `2 2 2`). Is there a way of doing this without a loop?

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go this way:

Reshape the vector so that it is a 3×x matrix:

```
x=[1:12];
xx=reshape(x,3,[]);
% xx is now [1 4 7 10; 2 5 8 11; 3 6 9 12]
```

after that

```
yy = sum(xx,1)./size(xx,1)
```

and now

```
y = reshape(repmat(yy, size(xx,1),1),1,[])
```

produces exactly your wanted result.

Your parameter `3`, denoting the number of values, is only used at one place and can easily be modified if needed.

Comment: Thanks thats great! Just a follow up. If you reshape the matrix, but there the size of the vector isn't divisible by 3, how will the matrix be reshaped?

Answer (score 3):

You may find the mean of each trio using:

`x = 1:12;

m = mean(reshape(x, 3, []));`

To duplicate the mean and reshape to match the original vector size, use:

`y = m(ones(3,1), :) % duplicates row vector 3 times

y = y(:)'; % vector representation of array using linear indices`

Comment: `mean` is better than doing it manually, and the indexing with `ones()` and `y(:)` are nice approaches, too. But I would transpose with `.'`, not with `'`.

Comment: I know this is an old answer. Still, consider replacing `'` with `.'` as suggested. Reason: `'` without `.` is used to get the *complex conjugate* transpose knows as [`ctranspose`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html). When using complex values, this will be problematic and hard to find. Refer to the documentation: *The nonconjugate transpose operator, `A.`', performs a transpose without conjugation. That is, it does not change the sign of the imaginary parts of the elements.*